# Oracle 12c SQL: Missing column Headers in result

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle12c

I want to understand why my columns are missing their headers.

Consider this table:

```
SQL> DESC customer;

Name         Null?    Type         
------------ -------- ------------ 
CUST_ID      NOT NULL NUMBER(5)    
CUST_NAME             VARCHAR2(15) 
ACCOUNT_ID            VARCHAR2(10) 
ACCOUNT_TYPE          VARCHAR2(2)  
STATE                 VARCHAR2(2)
```

When I select * from the table in SQL*Plus, the result is missing the column headers.

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM customer;

     90001 B and B         A-11101    PR AK
     90002 XYZ             A-11102    CM NJ
     90003 JJ Sons         A-11103    CM NJ
     90004 Exxon           A-11104    PR NY
     90005 ABC             A-11105    CM NY
     90006 Smith Co.       A-11106    CM MD
     90007 Brown Co.       A-11107    CM MD
     90008 Cooper Inc.     A-11108    PR MD

8 rows selected.
```

But when I use SQL Developer, the column headers are displayed.

Why? And, knowing that, how do I make them display with SQL*Plus?

My goal is to display the tables with the headers. If there are other details I need to add, let me know.

Heading is set to `ON`.

Comment: Why? : because column names are not a record

Comment: Is that a default? Should selecting the columns by name then list the column names? I'm asking 'should' because SQL Developer displays the column headers, but SQL*Plus is not.

Comment: I sure sounds as if heading is `off`. What does `show heading` give you?

Comment: It shows heading `ON`

Comment: It is because my pagesize was set to `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `pagesize` was set to `0`. I don't know why this would cause the column headers to disappear, but it did. If someone can explain better than me, I'll gladly accept their answer in leu of mine.

I set `pagesize` to `14`, and my column headers appeared.

Comment: [From the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG095): "*You can set PAGESIZE to **zero** to suppress all headings, page breaks, titles, the initial blank line, and other formatting information*"

Answer (score 0):

SQL*Plus has changed the default behavior in ORACLE 12c.

With

```
SQL> set head on
```

you get back to the previous behavior.

With

```
SQL> set pagesize *n*
```

every *n* rows the header will be repeated.